# Unity UWP bluetooth barcode scanner

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, hid, hololens

I've been looking into the unity Input debug to try and figure out a way where, I can read the string coming off a bluetooth barcode scanner.
The device is registered as Bluetooth HID Input device, and inside unity Input Debug, it shows as Broadcom Wireless keyboard (unsupported though...).
Any tips on how to read just the string? (the end character is 'enter' after each string)
On UI input fields it does read the string and dismisses it (with the enter end char). But doing this on Hololens is quite counter intuitive since the keyboard shows up covering almost all your fov.

Comment: Have you tried to pair the scanner with the HoloLens device? Currently, HoloLens only supports BLE mousses, keyboards, and Bluetooth audio output (A2DP) devices, so it is better to check that the scanner could be recognized as a Bluetooth HID Input device in the HoloLens first. For more information, please see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12636/hololens-pair-bluetooth-devices

Comment: That's already working, if I open any input field on the hololens and scan a barcode, it will fill in what it scanned.

Comment: My question was, how can I read the string coming in from the HID device without forcing an input field always on ...

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to try TMP_InputFields, it will show up a virtual keyboard by default, but you can control the visibility of the virtual keyboard. You can test this feature from MixedRealityKeyboardExample.unity which is located at Assets/MRTK/Examples/Experimental/MixedRealityKeyboard/Scenes/, and check the "Hide Soft Keyboard" checkbox in the MRTKTMPInputField component of the MRKeyboardInputField (TMP) object.

Comment: I'm already using TMP_InputField but if i hide the keyboard, the barcode input no longer happens

Comment: @HoriaHodis Have you tried anyway to get the stream from the device? We think the standard Unity UI input handler or getting data from the device itself will be a good path. Otherwise, if your need isn't specifically for Unity immersive App and you are open to use the 2D flat app, the pure UWP app with 2D XAML controls can be used then as a solution.

Comment: Not really sure how to read the stream, but I did look into Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice on how it could possibly be done ... However Unity complains it can't find the namespace and manually adding the dll was quite a hassle when compiling for arm ...